# Get specific lines from a text file

Tags: unix, shell, file-io

I am working on a UNIX box, and trying to run an application, which gives some debug logs to the standard output. I have redirected this output to a log file, but now wish to get the lines where the error is being shown.

My problem here is that a simple

```
cat output.log | grep FAIL
```

does not help out. As this shows only the lines which have FAIL in them. I want some more information along with this. Like the 2-3 lines above this line with FAIL. Is there any way to do this via a simple shell command? I would like to have a single command line (can have pipes) to do the above.

Comment: can you show how your logfile is formatted? while -B and -A work indeed, they are just ugly hacks. some of your logs may be even longer. if for example you indent with \t each line in a FAIL, you could filter one entry out more exactly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

grep -A $NUM

This will print $NUM lines of trailing context after matches.

-B $NUM prints leading context.

> man grep is your best friend.

So in your case:

> cat log | grep -A 3 -B 3 FAIL

Comment: Works nicely with GNU grep; is not part of standard (POSIX, Unix) grep.

Answer (score 9):

```
grep -C 3 FAIL output.log
```

Note that this also gets rid of the [useless use of cat (UUOC)](http://web.archive.org/web/20140123014909/http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).

Answer (score 3):

I have two implementations of what I call `sgrep`, one in Perl, one using just pre-Perl (pre-GNU) standard Unix commands.  If you've got GNU `grep`, you've no particular need of these.  It would be more complex to deal with forwards and backwards context searches, but that might be a useful exercise.

Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/perl/v5.8.8/bin/perl -w
#
# @(#)$Id: sgrep.pl,v 1.6 2007/09/18 22:55:20 jleffler Exp $
#
# Perl-based SGREP (special grep) command
#
# Print lines around the line that matches (by default, 3 before and 3 after).
# By default, include file names if more than one file to search.
#
# Options:
# -b n1     Print n1 lines before match
# -f n2     Print n2 lines following match
# -n        Print line numbers
# -h        Do not print file names
# -H        Do     print file names

use strict;
use constant debug => 0;
use Getopt::Std;
my(%opts);

sub usage
{
    print STDERR "Usage: $0 [-hnH] [-b n1] [-f n2] pattern [file ...]\n";
    exit 1;
}

usage unless getopts('hnf:b:H', \%opts);
usage unless @ARGV >= 1;

if ($opts{h} && $opts{H})
{
    print STDERR "$0: mutually exclusive options -h and -H specified\n";
    exit 1;
}

my $op = shift;

print "# regex = $op\n" if debug;

# print file names if -h omitted and more than one argument
$opts{F} = (defined $opts{H} || (!defined $opts{h} and scalar @ARGV > 1)) ? 1 : 0;
$opts{n} = 0 unless defined $opts{n};

my $before = (defined $opts{b}) ? $opts{b} + 0 : 3;
my $after  = (defined $opts{f}) ? $opts{f} + 0 : 3;

print "# before = $before; after = $after\n" if debug;

my @lines = (); # Accumulated lines
my $tail  = 0;  # Line number of last line in list
my $tbp_1 = 0;  # First line to be printed
my $tbp_2 = 0;  # Last line to be printed

# Print lines from @lines in the range $tbp_1 .. $tbp_2,
# leaving $leave lines in the array for future use.
sub print_leaving
{
    my ($leave) = @_;
    while (scalar(@lines) > $leave)
    {
        my $line = shift @lines;
        my $curr = $tail - scalar(@lines);
        if ($tbp_1 <= $curr && $curr <= $tbp_2)
        {
            print "$ARGV:" if $opts{F};
            print "$curr:" if $opts{n};
            print $line;
        }
    }
}

# General logic:
# Accumulate each line at end of @lines.
# ** If current line matches, record range that needs printing
# ** When the line array contains enough lines, pop line off front and,
#    if it needs printing, print it.
# At end of file, empty line array, printing requisite accumulated lines.

while (<>)
{
    # Add this line to the accumulated lines
    push @lines, $_;
    $tail = $.;

    printf "# array: N = %d, last = $tail: %s", scalar(@lines), $_ if debug > 1;

    if (m/$op/o)
    {
        # This line matches - set range to be printed
        my $lo = $. - $before;
        $tbp_1 = $lo if ($lo > $tbp_2);
        $tbp_2 = $. + $after;
        print "# $. MATCH: print range $tbp_1 .. $tbp_2\n" if debug;
    }

    # Print out any accumulated lines that need printing
    # Leave $before lines in array.
    print_leaving($before);
}
continue
{
    if (eof)
    {
        # Print out any accumulated lines that need printing
        print_leaving(0);
        # Reset for next file
        close ARGV;
        $tbp_1 = 0;
        $tbp_2 = 0;
        $tail  = 0;
        @lines = ();
    }
}
```

Pre-Perl Unix solution (using plain `ed`, `sed`, and `sort` - though it uses `getopt` which was not necessarily available back then):

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
# @(#)$Id: old.sgrep.sh,v 1.5 2007/09/15 22:15:43 jleffler Exp $
#
#   Special grep
#   Finds a pattern and prints lines either side of the pattern
#   Line numbers are always produced by ed (substitute for grep),
#   which allows us to eliminate duplicate lines cleanly.  If the
#   user did not ask for numbers, these are then stripped out.
#
#   BUG: if the pattern occurs in in the first line or two and
#   the number of lines to go back is larger than the line number,
#   it fails dismally.

set -- `getopt "f:b:hn" "$@"`

case $# in
0)  echo "Usage: $0 [-hn] [-f x] [-b y] pattern [files]" >&2
    exit 1;;
esac

# Tab required - at least with sed (perl would be different)
# But then the whole problem would be different if implemented in Perl.
number="'s/^\\([0-9][0-9]*\\)       /\\1:/'"
filename="'s%^%%'"      # No-op for sed

f=3
b=3
nflag=no
hflag=no
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
    -f) f=$2; shift 2;;
    -b) b=$2; shift 2;;
    -n) nflag=yes; shift;;
    -h) hflag=yes; shift;;
    --) shift; break;;
    *)  echo "Unknown option $1" >&2
        exit 1;;
    esac
done
pattern="${1:?'No pattern'}"
shift

case $# in
0)  tmp=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/`basename $0`.$$
    trap "rm -f $tmp ; exit 1" 0
    cat - >$tmp
    set -- $tmp
    sort="sort -t: -u +0n -1"
    ;;
*)  filename="'s%^%'\$file:%"
    sort="sort -t: -u +1n -2"
    ;;
esac

case $nflag in
yes)    num_remove='s/[0-9][0-9]*://';;
no)     num_remove='s/^//';;
esac
case $hflag in
yes)    fileremove='s%^$file:%%';;
no)     fileremove='s/^//';;
esac

for file in $*
do
    echo "g/$pattern/.-${b},.+${f}n" |
    ed - $file |
    eval sed -e "$number" -e "$filename" |
    $sort |
    eval sed -e "$fileremove" -e "$num_remove"
done

rm -f $tmp
trap 0
exit 0
```

The shell version of `sgrep` was written in February 1989, and bug fixed in May 1989.  It then remained unchanged except for an administrative change (SCCS to RCS transition) in 1997 until 2007, when I added the `-h` option.  I switched to the Perl version in 2007.

Answer (score 3):

http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Complicator_0x27_s_Gloves.aspx

You can use `sed` to print specific lines, lets say you want line 20

`sed '20 p' -n` FILE_YOU_WANT_THE_LINE_FROM

Done.

-n prevents echoing lines from the file. The part in quotes is a `sed` rule to apply, it specifies that you want the rule to apply to line 20, and you want to print.

Answer (score 1):

With [GNU grep on Windows](http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ grep --context 3 FAIL output.log

$ grep --help | grep context
```

```
  -B, --before-context=NUM  print NUM lines of leading context
  -A, --after-context=NUM   print NUM lines of trailing context
  -C, --context=NUM         print NUM lines of output context
  -NUM                      same as --context=NUM
```

Comment: btw, I *do* know that the question has the tag 'unix', I merely tested it on Windows.